# Copying an image from the gallery and then deleting it

Tags: android, android-gallery

I have an AsyncTask that copies the picture that was just taken to the location I have specified and then the original photo gets deleted. However, I keep getting an error most of the time.

```
final String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.SIZE,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
                BaseColumns._ID,};

        u = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        boolean found = false;

        if (CurrentFile != null)
        {               
            if ((u != null) && (CurrentFile.length() > 0))
            {
                Looper.prepare();   
                getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, new LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>(){

                    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
                        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(ExpenseReport.this, u, projection, null, null, null);
                        return loader;
                    }

                    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor c) {
                        if ((c != null) && (c.moveToFirst())){

                            do 
                            {

                                for (String sGallery : GlobalInfo.GalleryList){

                                    if (sGallery.equalsIgnoreCase(c.getString(1))){
                                        found = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                } 
                                if (!found){
                                    File f = new File(c.getString(2));


                                    if ((f.exists()) && (CurrentFile.length() < c.getLong(0)) && (CurrentFile.delete())){

                                        try
                                        {
                                            CurrentFile.createNewFile();
                                            FileChannel source = null;
                                            FileChannel destination = null;
                                            try{
                                                source = new FileInputStream(f).getChannel();
                                                destination = new FileOutputStream(CurrentFile).getChannel();
                                                destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
                                            }
                                            finally{

                                                if (source != null)
                                                    source.close();

                                                if (destination != null)
                                                    destination.close();
                                            }
                                        }
                                        catch (IOException e)
                                        {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                            GlobalInfo.LOG("", "Couldn't Copy The File");

                                        }
                                    }
                                    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                                    Bitmap bitmap=null;
                                    try {
                                        bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, CurrentUri);
                                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                                        e1.printStackTrace();

                                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                                        e1.printStackTrace();

                                    }
                                    if(bitmap.getWidth()<2000) 
                                        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), false);
                                    else
                                        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 2000, 2000, false);

                                    try {
                                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(CurrentFile);
                                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();

                                    }

                                    cr.delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                                            BaseColumns._ID + "=" + c.getString(3), null);

                                    break;                        
                                }
                            } 
                            while (c.moveToNext());
                        }
                    }

                    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {                        
                    }

                });
                Looper.loop();
            }
        }
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
07-26 09:38:58.060: E/CursorWindow(1566): Bad request for field slot 0,1. numRows = 14, numColumns = 1
07-26 09:38:58.107: W/dalvikvm(1566): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 1 failed
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:361)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:135)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at com.report.expense.ExpenseReport$FinishPhotoTask$1.onLoadFinished(ExpenseReport.java:1131)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at com.report.expense.ExpenseReport$FinishPhotoTask$1.onLoadFinished(ExpenseReport.java:1)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:425)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(LoaderManager.java:559)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at com.report.expense.ExpenseReport$FinishPhotoTask.doInBackground(ExpenseReport.java:1115)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at com.report.expense.ExpenseReport$FinishPhotoTask.doInBackground(ExpenseReport.java:1)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at     android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
07-26 09:38:58.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1566):     ... 4 more
```

(ExpenseReport.java:1115):

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, new LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>(){
```

(ExpenseReport.java:1131):

```
if (sGallery.equalsIgnoreCase(c.getString(1))){
```

EDIT:
I'm trying to get the size, name, location and id of the picture that was just taken by comparing a list of photo names before and after I take a photo. The problem is, sometimes this code works fine and other times it gives me this error.

Comment: What does your query and your table look like? You're trying to read the second column from a bunch of rows that only contain a single column.

Comment: Did my edit answer your question?

Comment: Yep. Perhaps printing the result of getColumnNames() on the Cursor will provide some hint of what's happening (if the error is easy to reproduce)?

Comment: Do you want to post it as an answer to get the bounty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened was I had more than one LoaderManager in my activity with the ID 0 so the query was returning the columns from before (which was only the photo name and nothing else, thanks Michael for the tip to look at my Column Names)

Answer (score 0):

(Creating an answer from my comment as suggested by the OP):

You can use the `getColumnNames` method on your `Cursor` to get a list of the columns you're actually getting from the `MediaStore`. Hopefully that'll provide some hint of what's going on.